# An additive property of integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a_0, p$ be any positive integers,defining:

$$a_{n+1} = \begin{cases}\frac{a_n}{p} &, a_n \text{ divisible by p}\\ a_n + k_n/l_n/o_n.. &, a_n \text{ odd}. \end{cases}$$

Now choose the sequence of positive integers ${k_n}$, ${f_n}$ or ${c_n}$,... such that:

$a_{n+1} $ is divisible by $p$ and $a_m=1$ where $m$ is any positive integer, now define:

$$f_0=\sum _{ c=0 }^{ c=m }{ { k }_{ c } } $$

$$f_1=\sum _{ c=0 }^{ c=m }{ { l }_{ c } } $$

$$f_2=\sum _{ c=0 }^{ c=m }{ { o }_{ c } } $$ and so on

Let $V$=min${f_g}$

Then $f_m$ is always of the form $V+(p-1)d$ where $d$ is some particular integer

I am horrible with mathematical notations, therefore I clarify the process by giving an example:

Let $a_0=47$ and $p=7$

$47+2= 49 ,49/7=7, 7/7=1$,therefore $V=2+0+0=2$

So $f_m=2+6d$

$47+9=56, 56/7=8, 8+6=14, 14/7=2, 2+5=7, 7/7=1$

$f_2=9+6+5=20=2+6(3)$

let $a_0=50$ and $p=16$

$50+14=64, 64/16=4, 4+12 =16, 16/16=1$,

$14+12=26=V$

$f_m=26+15d$

$50+30=80, 80/16=5, 5+11=16, 16/16=1$

$f_2=30+11=41=26+15(1)$

How to prove or disprove the general result?

PS: **I would be grateful if someone takes pain to re-write the question in a better form with suitable notations.**

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't follow all of your notation, but based on your process I think this is your proposition:

> Let $a_0$ be an integer and $p$ be a prime.
>
> Starting from $a_0$, construct *any* sequence $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ such that:
>
> $a_i \equiv 0 \mod p \Rightarrow \;a_{i+1} = \dfrac{a_i}{p}$
>
> $a_i \not\equiv 0 \mod p, \;a_i > 1 \Rightarrow a_{i+1} > a_i,\;a_{i+1} \equiv 0 \mod p$
>
> $a_i = 1 \Rightarrow \;a_{i+1} = 1$.
>
> Let $k_i = \begin{cases}0&a_i \equiv 0 \mod p \\
> a_{i+1}-a_i&a_i \not\equiv 0 \mod p
> \end{cases}$
>
> Then $\sum \{ k_i\} \mod p-1$ is a constant.

It seems:

- $\sum \{ k_i\} \equiv 1-a_0 \mod p-1$
- The condition $p$ is a prime is redundant.
- And we could use

> $a_i \not\equiv 0 \mod p, \;a_i > 1 \Rightarrow a_{i+1} \equiv 0 \mod p,\;a_{i+1} \ne 0$

The process here is somewhat similar to summing the digits of number expressed in base $p$ (which is congruent to the original number modulo $p-1$) but with a few detours thrown in.

Maybe someone else can outline a proof, otherwise I might have a crack later.